# Can I "download" a data uri without having to do it all myself?

Tags: c#, base64, webclient, data-uri

Maybe it is not the responsibility of a class named WebClient to turn a data uri into a byte[], but I tried

```
var client = new WebClient();
var result = client.DownloadData(uri);
```

given an uri looking like

> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

and got a WebException saying

> The URI prefix is not recognized.

How do I decode a data uri in the easiest way?

The problem with decoding such an uri with

`Convert.FromBase64String(str)` is that I need to extract the part

> R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

first, which of course is a trivial task.

However, when files get large, that will require me to allocate a lot of memory just to get an almost equal string. It is a mystery that `Convert.FromBase64String` does not have an offset parameter.

Do I need to do the whole base64 decoding myself if I do not want that extra allocation?

Comment: base64 is notoriously unsuitable for large storage.
on a side note, if you have a base64 encoded string already, why do you need to pass that through a `WebClient` first?

Comment: I hoped to have it converted by the `WebClient`.

Answer (score 0):

afaik, you could transform only a portion of the string by using a specific `Encoding` base class. (as opposed to converting the whole thing in one go)

if you're dealing with web stuff, i guess you want UTF8

something among these lines :
(this example does not do *exactly* what you want to do)

```
string completeMessage = "";
int byteStepSize = 4;

for(int i=0; i < byteStepSize; i+= byteStepSize)
{
    string subStr = str.SubString(i, i+byteStepSize);
    completeMessage += encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(subStr));
}
```

You could (theoretically) stream through a base64 encoded string this way, preventing the need to allocate it entirely in one go.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot/do not want to create an extra substring if the file is big.

Comment: well the idea behind that setup is that you could use a loop to keep the sub string allocation / memory footprint smaller.

Comment: For converting *from* arbitrary bytes *to* base 64, you can work 3 bytes at a time. Since every 3 input bytes produces 4 output characters. Which should tell you that working 3 characters at a time converting in the other direction is *not* safe to assume. (You can work 4 characters at a time, however)